# SQL no identifier, only timestamp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

At my project we work with an SQL 2008 database with read-only rights. In this case i like to save an identifier of of an row in my MYSQL database.

In MYSQl databases it is used to use an autoincrement PK ID field. But in this SQL database there is only one unique field that is named timestamp.

[image]
[image]

So when i try to get this field by SQL query and save it my my MYSQL database in an VARCHAR field that looks like this:

[image]

This does not look like the identefier in my MS SQL studio..

What is the best way to save an key of my SQL database in an MYSQL table so i can call that row later?

Comment: It doesn't look like `timestamp` is the key for that table.  It looks like a combination of `License No_`, `Perpetration Date`, `Perpetration Time`, and `Costkind lease company` is the key.  This table doesn't have an "identity" column, its key is a composite of those four other columns.

Comment: You should be using the primary key on the SQL 2008 DB and nto the timestamp as it's not unique, and updatable.  That 2008 Scheme looks pretty sadistic, have fun. :)

Comment: In SQL Server, [`timestamp`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) is a binary column.  Try to store it in a binary MySQL column, instead of a varchar.

Comment: @David: in SQL Server, a `timestamp` is an "automatically generated binary number" that is "guaranteed to be unique within a database".  The name is a bit of a misnomer.

Comment: @Andomar: You linked to a page for SQL Server 2000. FWIW, [that syntax is deprecated](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/LIBRARY/ms182776%28v=sql.120%29.aspx), and Microsoft plans to remove it from future versions. Which future version? We don't know.

Comment: @David: this combinations is not really unique. The "Perpetration Time" does not contain a time so that is the problem in this case.

Comment: @MyItchyChin indeed:P

Comment: @JelleP: If this combination is not unique then it can't be the primary key for the table.  According to the table definition in the screen shot, it *is* the primary key.  The primary key *must* be unique.  Each individual field in this composite key may not *itself* be unique, but the combination of them must be.

Comment: @David: oké i think you are right. Theoretical is it possible that those four keys contains the same data but the db will not allow that according your answer.. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Timestamp changes everytime an update is made to a record. It's very useful for concurrency checks to test whether the record has changed since it was last retrieved but it won't be the primary key. From your diagram, it looks like the primary key (note the PK next to the fields) is a composite of...

```
License No_
Perpetration Date
Perpetration Time
Costkind lease company
```

You would be able to hold a string combination of these in your database e.g....

```
[License No_] + '|' + [Perpetration Date] + '|' + [Perpetration Time] + '|' + [Costkind lease company]
```

But it would have to be on the assumption that none of the field values will change in order to link up properly.